# Función como valor de respuest en JS

Tags: javascript

Encontré el siguiente ejemplo en un curso y no lo entiendo.

Este código toma dos argumentos, en este caso dos años y produce una respuesta de verdadera si 1912 esta dentro de esos dos años, de otro modo el resultado es falso. Ejemplo:

```
 function yearToCheck(year) {
    return function (x, y) {
        return year >= x && year <= y;
    }
   
}

const checkYears = yearToCheck(1912);

checkYears(1900,1913) // true 
checkYears(1900, 1911) // false
```

¿Por qué la función anónima "función (x, y)" toma los valores 1900 y 1913/1911 de la variable checkYears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `yearToCheck` funciona como una especie de "fábrica" que produce funciones que evalúan si un año está dentro de un intervalo. Esto tiene la ventaja de crear funciones diferentes sin tener que cambiar su código.

En la instrucción: `yearToCheck(1912)`, se crea una función que recibirá como parámetros dos años que serán los límites inferior y superior. Lo cual se vería así:

```
const checkYears = function(x, y){
    return 1912 >= x && 1912 <= y;
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder Lobos.